# How do I fix CPU usage at 100% on a windows server running php?

Tags: php, windows, azure, iis, virtual-machine

I am running php on a Windows server (2019) VM in Azure. On that VM I have IIS v10, PHP v8.2.3, and MySQL v8 running several Wordpress sites. In task manager and perfmon, I see that there can be 3 or 4 fastcgi processes running, that combined, use 100% cpu and slow my Wordpress sites down to a crawl. This will happen at random times for up to 8 hours and then resolve for days. I have seen answers for this but none that seem to fit or are very detailed. I am fairly certain that this is not php code errors - I have checked php error logs and don't see anything that should cause this. Thanks for any help!!! At this point I could really use it!

Comment: I would recommend switching from fastcgi to fpm tbh. I used to have FastCGI on all my servers too a few years back and had frequent CPU usage issues as well but switching to FPM (and properly configuring it) fixed it for me.

Comment: Is FPM available for Windows Server? Is there good documentation anywhere on "properly configuring it"? Thanks!!!

Comment: I just found out (just now) that FPM isn't supported on WIndows ( https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62447 ). My apologies man.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? Swap space? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) complete PHP.ini to review configuration details 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Usually you need a profiler to dig further. Besides, PHP on Windows status isn't good, https://docs.lextudio.com/phpmanager/getting-started/supported-platforms#php-on-windows-status

Comment: This blog explains why php-cgi.exe has high CPU usage and how to fix it, you can see if it helps. https://bobcares.com/blog/php-cgi-exe-high-cpu/

Comment: I've looked through bobcares.com - didn't really help me.  Thanks though!  Possibly this is an issue with the VM on Azure.  Here are the details on that: it is a Standard B4ms - 4 virtual CPUs, 16 GiB ram, Max IOPS 2880. Here are other details as I get them:

Comment: Here are other details as I get them - of course at the moment the CPU is calmed down and only at about 3%:
A: 704
B: https://justpaste.it/5wifl
C: https://jpst.it/3E4qV
D: https://jpst.it/3E4rj
E: STATUS gives sql error in MYSQL Workbench
G: https://jpst.it/3E4se

Comment: php.ini = https://jpst.it/3E4sV

Hoping I have misconfigured something or possibly I could upgrade VM in Azure?

Comment: OS is Windows Server 2019 Datacenter... Thanks for any help you can provide!!!

Comment: @JackWalker  Your posting of B: should have been a few hundred lines of output from  SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  without the WHERE that restricted the results. Your G: is only a few lines and nomally is more than 100 lines.  It may take a minute or two for SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;  to complete.  Please replace these two or get a new link in justpaste.it for us.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks Wilson!!! Updated B is here: https://jpst.it/3E9OO.  However, I reran SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS in MySQL Workbench and it shows 1 row returned.

Comment: @JackWalker  From your MySQL Command Prompt (rather than workbench) can you run SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; then copy output to clipboard and save to file?

Comment: @JackWalker  From MySQL command prompt, please SHOW PLUGINS; and post the results.  Looking at your php.ini, there is a debug_trace listed, if you search for 'trace' in the ini, you should find the reference.  You may have several trace modules in the plugins that are active, contributing to 100% busy.

Comment: @JackWalker  Two more items to consider.  A) Volume Shadow Copy typically needs to be OFF for any base server.  B) Windows, Control Panel, Power Options Power setting should be FULL rather than saving a few $ on your power bill.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your Azure portal, Settings, Server parameters.

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=16384  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 12,934.
thread_cache_size=48  # from 10 to support 46 concurrent max_used_connections.
tmp_table_size=64M  # from ~ 640M for a more reasonable size.
max_heap_table_size=64M  # from 16M for best practice of always = tmp_table_size.
```

There are many more opportunities to improve performance. View my profile.

Observations,
We do not normally see both A) innodb_log_file_size and B) innodb_redo_log_capacity in a configuration.  Eventually, innodb_redo_log_capacity will replace innodb_log_file_size, when Azure enforces the new name only.
select_scan reported 114,985 full table scans.  Appropriate indexes will relieve much CPU busy. JetProfiler.com has a free version to assist in identifying the tables needing indexes.

Comment: Thanks so much Wilson. I am going to review and update these settings tonight. Would the original settings lead to a slowdown of the VM over time. I am confused as to why the server runs fine for a while and then all of a sudden CPU usage spikes to 100%. I really appreciate your time!!!!

Comment: It gets exhausted, tries to relieve things that can be slow for a while and sometimes returns to more typical processing timings.

Comment: Sorry Wilson - 1 more question... For the read_rnd_buffer_size, should it be 16384 with a "K" or is that value in bytes.

Comment: Jack, 16384, please.

Comment: UPDATE: The CPU started hitting 100% again this morning (several fast cgi processes causing the issue).  I updated the my.ini file as prescribed above and restarted the MySQL service.  Unfortunately the CPU dipped for a moment while the service was stopped but then jumped back up to 100% again once the service came back up.  The server had been running fine for the last couple of days. Is there anything else I can look into?

Comment: Could there be a misconfiguration with the Azure VM itself? What is strange to me is that in Azure the Percent CPU usage in Metrics shows nowhere near 100% cpu usage but  logged in to the VM, task manager shows 100%.  The VM I am using in Azure is Standard B4ms (4 vcpus, 16 GiB memory).  Is that enough for IIS running php and a few medium sized websites?

Comment: Here is what I am seeing in task manager: https://jpst.it/3Eq2d

Comment: Also ntoskrnl.exe occasionally jumps to 20% or more...

Comment: Also... even when I restart IIS the Fast CGI processes come back up immediately to take up 100% CPU. UGH! I have an on-prem server with the same setup and no issues with it. I'm really thinking this is Azure...

Comment: With 4 CPU's, When looking at VM CPUBusy/# cpu's for overall busy.  When looking at task manager that only goes to 100%, each process stands on its own for their percentage.  Give me a 24hours to look around for something to smooth the FAST CGI cpu utilization.  Do you have a FAST CGI .ini or configuration you could post for analysis.

Comment: Please view my profile and get in touch, SO is whining about extended discussions this morning.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257265/discussion-between-jack-walker-and-wilson-hauck).